# React useState is not picking initial state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I need a form values to be pre-filled with initial values coming in from redux state:

Issue is, REDUX is updated, but useState is not using the initial values passed in.

```js
// redux
const {
    [1]: stepInfo,
    error,
    saving,
} = useSelector((state) => state.implOnboard);

// local state
// setting up initial state
// =================================================================
const [name, setName] = React.useState(stepInfo.name);
const [description, setDescription] = React.useState(stepInfo.desc);
// =================================================================
```

> Input elements (the other one has value={description})

**both show empty fields instead of prefilled values**

```
<input
  id="impl-name"
  placeholder="gs-sentiment-analysis-impl-1"
  value={name} //  using here
  onChange={(e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
    // enable the editing status to true for this step if any state changes
    setEditingStepStatus(1, true);
  }}
/>
```

### Debug

```js
  console.log(name, description); // prints '', ''
  console.log(stepInfo); // but this prints the actual values that I want to show
```

Comment: Are you sure redux is set before the initial state is set?

Comment: @DBS, even if the redux is set later on, won't it re-render the component and re-set the initial value on ```useState``` ?

Comment: I genuinely don't know. That's why I am asking.

Comment: @Dilshan To set the initial values i am getting via an API call. That's the whole point.

Comment: I guess react component is initializing earlier. Maybe you should just use redux values in render?

Comment: "if the redux is set later on, won't it re-render the component and re-set the initial value on `useState`" No, absolutely not. React component state is initialized exactly once per mounting. If the redux state updates later then you will need to use an `useEffect` to update the local state when the redux state updates. WARNING: It's generally considered an anti-pattern to store passed props, redux state, etc into local component state; leads to stale state, just use the passed values directly.

Comment: @Nixton That way the user won't be able to edit the input fields.

Comment: @DrewReese Okay, that makes sense now. 
One question though, if I use the redux state (for initial value) as the value prop in the input element, wouldn't it stop the user to make changes to the input field? I tried that, it doesn't let the value to be altered.

Comment: Well, presumably you'd fix the `onChange` handler to dispatch the changes to your store, so no, I don't think it'd stop the user from making changes. It might be better to use an additional loading/fetching state and use conditional rendering in your UI if you're concerned about premature user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to [Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese), I was able to understand the issue at hand.

So I worked around and came up with this solution:

```js
// local state
// setting up initial state
// =================================================================
const [name, setName] = React.useState(stepInfo.name);
const [description, setDescription] = React.useState(stepInfo.desc);

// workaround 
React.useEffect(() => {
    setName(stepInfo.name);
    setDescription(stepInfo.desc);
}, [stepInfo.name, stepInfo.desc]);
// =================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a state value. You can directly use redux values in the input.It will fill the initial values for you. No need to use an additional state.And write reducer functions in redux and call them in onChange event

```
 <input
  id="impl-name"
  placeholder="gs-sentiment-analysis-impl-1"
  value={stepInfo.name} //  using here
  onChange={(e) => {
    //Call redux reducer function for updating name;
    // enable the editing status to true for this step if any state changes
    setEditingStepStatus(1, true);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: You mean I should dispatch a REDUX ACTION on every keystroke? It would be very inefficient for performance.

Comment: If that is an issue you may dispatch action using onBlur event.Hope this will work

Comment: Unless you are doing something really dumb in a reducer or can input tens of characters per second I doubt redux will be a bottleneck in your app.

Comment: @DrewReese The redux state for this functionality is pretty large. Since it is a step form, with 8 steps, it would be really inefficient to update the redux state for such small implemtnation.

Comment: @KaranKumar then don't use Redux. https://redux.js.org/faq/general#when-should-i-use-redux

Comment: @Dilshan Lets not jump to conclusions, we have solid reasons to use redux in this production application.

Comment: @KaranKumar when do you update the redux with the user values from input ? Does it happen when you click on Next or Submit button ?